# SQL - SELECT row where any of columns is of certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a `SELECT` query that would return rows where at least one of X columns is of certain value.

```
id    name    teamid     player1    player2    player3    ...    player12

1     Jane    2          43         46         12         ...    36
2     Mathew  6          12         56         18         ...    42
3     Shaun   8          53         55         12         ...    62
4     Jane    1          1          53         19         ...    34
5     Eugene  3          23         34         13         ...    44
```

In this table i have 14 columns (id, name and player1 to player12) and want to `SELECT` row of specific `teamid`, let's say `teamid='2'`, and return the name of column that contains for example number `12` in this row.

Is this even possible with MySQL?

Comment: Fix your broken schema

Comment: @Strawberry how comes it's broken? Players are virtual personas and to fill one's team he has to pick them, don't think there's better solution than this actually

Comment: A separate table storing teamplayers would represent an immeasurable improvement

Comment: @Strawberry still I'd have to store them in 12 columns right? Tried making an array with them and then decomposing it but this takes slightly.more time

Comment: No. You'd store then in two columns, and 12 rows (per team). This is the basic stuff of an RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, then:

```
select t.*,
       (case when player1 = 12 then 'player1'
             when player2 = 12 then 'player2'
             . . .
             when player12 = 12 then 'player12'
        end) player_with_12
from t
where t.teamid = 2;
```

You might want to revisit your data structure, so you have one row per `team` and `player`.

Comment: seems like this might do the trick, but i thought there's some easier workaround for this anyways :) will check in a moment if it works for me